# Proof of a point beween two different points. (Geometry)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm struggling with some of the logic writing this proof. This is the question:

Prove that if X is in AB (AB is a line segment) with X =/= B, then dist(AX) < dist(AB).

Logically this makes perfect sense.  The problem is that I struggle with putting it into words.  This is my attempt.

Proof:
Towards a contradiction, suppose that the distance AX >= AB.  Then by definition, AX + XB >= AB.  This implies that X is not in the line segment AB.  =><=

Am I close or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X \ne B$,
$dist(X, B) > 0$.

Since
$dist(A, X) + dist(X, B)
=dist(A, B)
$,
$dist(A, X)
=dist(A, B)- dist(X, B)
< dist(A, B)
$.

Comment: Wow that is very easy to understand thanks!

Comment: but is my approach wrong?

Comment: First, I would separate the cases $X = B$ and $X \ne B$. Also, you somehow have to use the fact that X is *on* AB.

Comment: k I'll give it a try, thanks again